# With C# 7.0's new TaskLike async support is it possible to write an IObservable<T> generator

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await, system.reactive, c#-7.0

C#7 is out and I see they have opened up the **async** **await** keywords to allow anything you want. However the surface area of the API seems [very large](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/master/src/System.Threading.Tasks.Extensions/src/System/Threading/Tasks/ValueTask.cs) and I'm not sure of the limitations.

Specifically I'm interested if this is possible

```
int RandomNumber(){..}

public async IObservable<int> Generate(){
    while(true){
        await Observable.Timer(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1)).Select(_=>RandomNumber());

        await Observable.Timer(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2)).Select(_=>10);
    }
}
```

which I think is equivalent to

```
public IObservable<int> Generate(){
   return Observable.Timer(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1)).Select(_=>RandomNumber())
    .Concat(Observable.Timer(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2)).Select(_=>10))
    .Replay();

}
```

There is a link on [Reddit from a while](https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=2999791) ago discussing why async await could be as powerful as f# computation expressions if only they were allowed to be.

Answer (score 1):

I would guess no (for now):

The compiler has to somehow stitch together your code into a concrete type to construct and return. `IObservable<T>` isn't a type, so the compiler can't construct it.

Also, from 7.0 [Release Notes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/csharp/csharp-7#generalized-async-return-types):

> The new language feature means that async methods may return other
>   types in addition to Task, Task and void. The returned type must
>   still satisfy the async pattern, meaning a GetAwaiter method must be
>   accessible.

That isn't to say that someone couldn't build an `ObservableTask<T>` or something which would implement `IObservable<T>` and also fulfill the requirements of the Task API. It just hasn't been done (yet).

You still would have the issue of mismatch: `Task<T>` revolves around returning a 0-1 `T` objects, `IObservable<T>` returns 0-n `T` objects.